# Constraint layout with data binding

Tags: android

When use simple constraint layout it's working fine but when use data binding then it's not running,and preview is randering wrong and also binding methods are not finding show error 
**Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method item::onCardClick /app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml loc:16:27 - 16:43 ****\ data binding error ******

Without data binding

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="14dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Hello First"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Hello Second"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/line"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
With databinding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.rv.cnstnt_example.MyPojoClass"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:onClick="@{item::onCardClick}"
        android:paddingTop="14dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@{item.name}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@{item.dob}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/line"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

[image]
MyPojoClass.java

```
   public class MyPojoClass
{
    private String name = "Vineet";
    private String dob = "22 jun 2018";

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void onCardClick(){
        Log.e("DATA","CLICK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share image of wrong rendering and also the layout file

Comment: i have added screen shots and code of layout

Comment: if you click on the red exclamation mark in the preview, what does it say?

Comment: Hey, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

in `MyPojoClass` class change the method `onCardClick` to accept `View` as an argument. It should be

```
public void onCardClick(View view) { 
     Log.e("DATA","CLICK"); 
}
```

Comment: i tried but doesn,t work,saying Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android::onCardClick' with parameter type lambda on android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.